# Sniff GSM packets Wireshark

Tags: sniffer, gsm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartphone / GSM Sniffer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5997/smartphone-gsm-sniffer)

I noticed in a video on youtube is possible to sniff gsm traffic using wireshark.

How is this possible ? Do I need a GSM modem to acheive this ?

Thanks

Comment: At least you'll need a base station

Comment: @HenningKlevjer could you be more specific please

Comment: I don't know too much about this, but if you're going to sniff gsm signals you will need something to read the medium.. Cell phones will automatically hand themselves over to the base station with the strongest signal, so that's a start. If you want to collect the signal "in flight" that might be possible with some sort of antenna, but you must keep in mind that these signals  hop between frequencies, etc. Some things to google: BSS, FHSS. You might actually be able to buy a BSS online. It's an interesting question!

Comment: in order for people to answer your question - provide them with more details. What video have you seen?

Comment: Without a modem/phone/SDR it's not possible. You probably saw the GNUradio & gr-gsm/airprobe video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eofnb7zr8QE) - which used to capture, analyze and format the signal and packets, which can be shown on wireshark with the GSMTAP format.